# mPDF: Is there a way to embed pdf file inside $mpdf.WriteHTML()?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using `mPDF` library to create a PDF file. I want to embed a separate pdf file inside my pdf. This is my code:

```
$url = "new_folder/myfile.pdf";

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="text-align:center;">
<embed src="/'.$url.'" width="350" height="250"></div>'); //doesn't work

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="text-align:center;">
<iframe src="/'.$url.'" width="350" height="250"></div>'); //doesn't work
```

When I execute the code, my pdf file is completely blank. Why? Is there any other way to embed pdf file?

Comment: So is there any way for the user to view the other pdf file inside the pdf?

Comment: mPDF has an [`importPage`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/importpage-v8.html) which might get you closer to what you are looking for.