# mPDF: embedded PDF file is not rendered

Tags: php, mpdf

When I try to convert HTML like this:

`<object data="/path/to/file" type="application/pdf"> <embed src="/path/to/file" type="application/pdf"> </object>`

or like this:

`<embed src="/path/to/file" type="application/pdf">`

I get a blank page. Is there a way to insert a PDF file from "embed" tag into generated PDF?

As I understand this question was already asked at [mPDF: Is there a way to embed pdf file inside $mpdf.WriteHTML()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755258/mpdf-is-there-a-way-to-embed-pdf-file-inside-mpdf-writehtml) , but unfortunately it has no answer.

Comment: _"but unfortunately it has no answer"_ - the hint in the comments, that an `importPage` method exists, still sounds like the first thing to pursue here though, I'd say.

Comment: Yes, but it does not explain is it possible to import a PDF via the <embed> tag into generated PDF

Comment: Nah, I very much doubt that is possible with that library. You might perhaps have a better chance with `wkhtmltopdf` - that is based on the Qt WebKit rendering engine. But there is no direct PHP implementation that I know of, this tool needs to be used via command line.